# Is there a way to put duplicate value to a json array via post method? I got error 500 if try to push an item twice

Tags: arrays, json, angular, post

Is there a way to put duplicate value to a json array via post method? I got error 500 if try to push an item twice.I use Angular 13.I thought an array can hold the same object more hence it has indexcies not key value pairs.May be in the post method options object can i add some header options or in json server configuration set something to not give internal error 500?Or should i restructure the "db"?It works how I wish when I add just once an item.

**structure on json-server endpoint:**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "product_1",
    "net": 8900
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "product_2",
    "net": 10450
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "product_3",
    "net": 16200
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "product_4",
    "net": 17000
  }
]
```

**post methods service:**

```
  postItem(body: any): Observable<InputData> {
    return this.http.post<InputData>(this.arr_url, body);
  }
```

**function to add item:**

```
  addToArr() {
    this.postItem.postItem({id: this.id, name: this.name, net: this.net}).subscribe(data => console.log(data));

  }
```

Comment: If you are getting error 500 there should be an issue on the server side, not on the angular, what is the 500 error message, also I do not see any duplicatcy in your structure?

Comment: There is no duplicates because i cant insert.This is the errerror: "Error: Insert failed, duplicate id\n    at Function.insert (C:\\Users\\User\\Workspace\\ng\\node_modules\\lodash-id\\src\\index.js:49:18)\n

Comment: are you trying to push an item where primary key is id, and you want to save two entry in the table with the same id

Comment: if i insert duplicate manually ist works.I think its somthing json-server configuration problem but i dont know what is exactly

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: just simply rename id to something else. Seems like it's a reserved keyword in json-server.